# Create a WSS 3.0 or SharePoint 2007 project using Visual Studio 2010 beta 2

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, visual-studio-2010

I have installed WSS 3.0 and Visual Studio 2010 Beta 2 on a Windows 2003 x86 VM and I am unable to create a Sharepoint Project. I keep getting the error below.

"A SharePoint server is not installed on this computer. A SharePoint server must be installed to work with SharePoint projects.

I am selecting C# .Net 3.5 as the .Net version and then I am trying to create a Empty SharePoint project.  Why do I keep getting the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Corey is correct. You will only be able to use VS2010 to create workflows for SharePoint 2007. For all other development on SharePoint 2007 you should stick to VS 2005/2008 with WSPbuilder, STSDEV or VS SharePoint Extensions.

Answer (score 3):

I'm afraid Visual Studio 2010 only supports creating SharePoint project types with SharePoint 2010.

Comment: Are you sure? Do you have any references or is this something you have tried yourself?

Comment: Yes, I've tried it myself as well as attended SharePoint 2010 Ignite training where they first told me about it.  You can of course still develop against previous versions without using the SharePoint project types just like you did with Visual Studio 2008.

Answer (score 1):

Actually that is possible as soon as you do not want to Debug or Deploy directly from VS2010.

All you need to do is to export from HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Shared Tools\Web Server Extensions\14 from a machine with SP2010 installed.

Creating a new Visual Studio Sharepoint 2010 project will allow you to build and package a solution targeting MOSS2007, while just modifying the DLL references to from 2010 to 20007 versions.

Registry key settings explained in more details:
http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sharepoint2010programming/thread/cda807f6-4edf-4efc-8e9b-4d446356c8ae

Building and packaging a solution in more details:
http://www.dotnetmafia.com/blogs/dotnettipoftheday/archive/2010/07/15/using-visual-studio-2010-sharepoint-templates-to-deploy-a-web-part-in-sharepoint-2007.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You should check [WSP Builder 2010 beta](http://keutmann.blogspot.com/2009/12/wspbuilder-2010-beta.html) for some backward compatibility.